# Blazing in his eyes

Tags: meaning, phrases

The following passage is taken from Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone.
I cannot understand exactly what the phrase 'blazing in his eyes' mean.  What is the subject of the verb 'blaze'?

> There was somethin' goin' on that night he hadn't counted on - I dunno
>   what it was, no one does - but somethin' about you stumped him, all
>   right'  Hagrid looked at Harry with warmth and respect blazing in his
>   eyes, but Harry, instead of feeling pleased and proud, felt quite sure
>   there had been a horrible mistake.

Comment: Warmth and respect are the subjects. They are blazing, or burning, in Hagrid's eyes. It's a metaphor for intensity.

Comment: @Silenus See the discussion in the comments following my answer. You may wish to provide an answer of your own.

Answer (score 1):

*Blazing* is a present participle, a verb which can be used to modify a noun. It is effectively an adjective in this form.

*Blazing* modifies the noun phrase *warmth and respect*.

As @Silenus says well in a comment, the term *[blazing](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=blaze)* means

> To shine or be resplendent with: *eyes that blazed hatred.*

*American Heritage*

It means show an intensity of emotion through an expression in and around the eyes.

Comment: Yes, this is certainly the correct answer to the question asked, and so this deserves to be the accepted answer. I get the feeling the question intended was actually "What does the idiom 'blazing in his eyes' mean?" or even "What's this sentence mean?". If so, there is a lesson about asking what is actually meant, here.

Comment: @TheNate I think Silenus gave a reasonably good explanation of the meaning as opposed to the form.

Comment: Agreed. I think that he answered the question intended but not asked while you answered the question asked but not intended. Tart this up with a bit more contextual application of your answer and you'd cover both.